# Any permanent solution in killing wild grape vines?

Tags: vines, permaculture

I have 80 acre with over 3/4 bush/trees situated about 1 mile from an old CN railway line (no longer in use) where people throw out their fruits among them, grapes.  The grapes seeds have made wild grape vines all over the property, in sizes ranging from less than a child's small finger to over 4 inches in diameter.  These vines are growing along our driveway among our stone fence created by the farmer over the years.  They are growing around, through, and up our beautiful old oak trees.
How to I permanently destroy the vines without hurting the trees.

Comment: There is no magic solution here. You need to cut them back and poison them. By the sounds of it you have a lot of work ahead of you, get er done.

Comment: Please see https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3846/how-do-i-get-rid-of-wild-grape-vines which may already have an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

This makes me think of a few permaculture tools that love woody food sources:

- Goats - they love to eat things head level and above
- Sheep - they love to eat woody things head level and below

After a few years of using these animals along with chickens to keep the grass down they will kill off anything living in the area if you provide enough animals to reverse the damage already caused.